# My error is Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010

[my Table Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vy7WQ.jpg)

This is my code: Please Help thank you. In my `command.ExecuteReader` error shows data type mismatch in criteria expression.

```
conn.Open()
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Physical]([PhysicalNo],[StockCode],[StockName],[SDate],[EditDate],[OnhandQty])" +
                       "VALUES(@PhysicalNo,@StockCode,@StockName,@SDate,@EditDate,@OnhandQty)"

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhysicalNo", txtPhysicalno.Text)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StockCode", cboStockCode.Text)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StockName", txtstockname.Text)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SDate", cboStockdate.Text)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EditDate", EditPicker.Text)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("OnhandQty", txtqty.Text)

Dim read1 As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader

While read1.Read

End While

conn.Close()
```

Comment: please convert your input to same as the table data type

Comment: **First**, you are missing an `@` in the last parameters.AddWithValue.
**Second**, you are using `ExecuteReader` for an insert statement. you should use `ExecuteNonQuery`. **Third**, [Don't use AddWithValue](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: @Chetan Sanghani what is the best way  than AddWithValue thank you for helping me.

Comment: command.Parameters.Add("@OnhandQty", SqlDbType.Int).Value  =    Convert.Toint32(txtqty.Text)

Answer (score 0):

`data type mismatch` error means that you are inserting values in table which are not matching with entered data-type.

from your column headings i think you need to insert `date-time` data type for date values and `int` datatype for number data-type values.

if this answer doesn't help please provide screen shot of your table design view.

Comment: your column data types are int,text,Date time and what i am seeing here is you are adding only text type of data-type. so try changing it according to your table data-type

Comment: Sha same error data type mismatch in criteria expression thank you for helping  me.

Answer (score 0):

For the AddWithValue method to work properly, it is neccessary to pass the value with the correct data type for the column in the database. This is most obviously required for the *SDate* and *EditDate* columns.

Example for *SDate*:

```
const DATEFORMAT As String = "dd.MM.yyyy";                
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SDate", _
              DateTime.ParseExact(cboStockdate.Text,DATEFORMAT, _ 
                                 System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, _
                                 System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None))
```

Obviously date format, *CultureInfo* and *DateTimeStyles* should be adjusted to what is appropriate in the context of your application. You might want to have a look at the *TryParse* method as well.

For the other columns conversion will probably work automatically during execution of the SQL, but still it is advisable to do explicit conversion when adding the parameter to the command.

An even better way to add the parameters would be to not use AddWithValue at all. You could use the Add method and explicitly sepcify the data type (on the database side) of the parameter.

```
Dim par As OleDbParameter = new OleDbParameter("@SDate", OleDbType.Date)
par.Value = DateTime.Parse(cboStockdate.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add(par)
```

The more specific approach to use *ParseExact* (like in the first code sample) to convert the text input to *DateTime* would apply here as well.

Comment: PhilS Thank you i will try it.

Comment: PhilS its not working the error is String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: PhilS same error String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. tahnk you for helping me.

Comment: @Hackweiser: That should be fixed with using the ParseExact method, as amended to the answer.